# Android Task and App Link - Check which is the previous Activity in task when app link opens an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-deep-link, android-app-links

**Scenario :**

In my application i have enabled app linking. So when an App link is triggered, i have set a dummy `AppLinkActivity (opens as "singleTask" to avoid creation of new task)` to receive and handle the url received through the app link. While handling the url, i have to check whether the app was showing the "`DownloadActivity`", if so then i have to show a dialog.

So when an App link is triggered, i will have the already existing task with existing activities and on top of that will be the AppLinkingActivity. In this case i have no way to know what the previous activity was, since i cannot pass anything via an intent.

**What i want to do**

When the AppLinkingActivity is opened via an app link, is there any way by which i can find out what was the `last shown activity(of my app) before` AppLinkingActivity in the same task?

--**Alternatively**--

If i exclude the "singleTask" in manifest then the AppLinkingActivity is opened in a new task. In this scenario, is there any way by which i can get the last shown(or topmost) activity in the previous task? If yes, i also need a way to navigate to that topmost activity in the previous task? In this scenario if i simply `finish()` AppLinkingActivity, then the control goes back to the which ever source that triggered the app link like browser or gmail app etc.

Is any of the above two requirements is possible?

Comment: What happens when you don't give anything and simply `finish()` AppLinkingActivity? Does it go back to your previous activity?

Comment: @sanjeev In "singleTask" launchMode, yes. The application goes back to the previous activity in the task stack. Otherwise(not in "singleTask"), if the app link is triggered from gmail, then when executing `finish()` gmail pops back up.

Comment: **In this case i have no way to know what the previous activity was, since i cannot pass anything via an intent** - Why? Is it necessary to pass data using only intent?

Comment: @sanjeev Sorry. By that i meant that i cannot pass anything into the AppLinkingActivity to determine what the previous activity was. All the solutions that i encountered on stackoverflow was in some way using values passed through intent from previous activity. Since this is opened from external intent i cannot differentiate which activity it is.

Comment: you can use shared prefs to store the data and later use it to pass the value to any activity and remove when necessary..